# how can i pass the data from parent component to child components without re rendering parent every time in react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-hooks, frontend

I have state in parent component that must be pass to the child parent this state for some actions supposed to update.know whats a problem ?
i have `useEffect()` hook in parent after each update my child and my parent component re- rendering .how can i do that without re rendering each time ?
should i use simple variable as list for passing ? if yes how can i update it each time and pass it ti child component
for know i just try with state hook in parent component
any suggestions?

Comment: If you are updating state in the parent then it will/should rerender. When components rerender they rerender their children (subtree). Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's not easy debugging code if you can't see what it's doing.

Comment: In general, changing of state *should* cause a re-render. If you want to manipulate a value without causing any re-renders, you can store it in a ref using `useRef` - but this is far less common

Comment: great i will use it next time @DrewReese

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you're trying to accomplish simply goes against the whole architecture of React. Any change in local component 'state' or passed 'props' to the component triggers a re-render. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? A code example would be nice...

Comment: This should be a comment instead of an answer, as it asks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

use memo to prevent render child component

```
Parent.js
---------

function Parent(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child data={data}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Parent


Child.js
--------


function Child({data}) {
  return (
    <div>
      {data}
    </div>
  );
}

export default React.memo(Child);
```